What does the term "organically bound" exactly mean?
I have come across terms like organically bound nitrogen, organically bound tritium, etc. Could you explain in detail what 'organically bound' means in these cases?

It means just what it says: chemically bound as a part of some organic molecule.

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

There may be confusion  between organic as part of organic compound in  chemistry context versus organic as BIO(trademark in EU/DE for organic food) in everyday life context. In your question context, it is the former.

"Organically bound" means the target molecule is bound to an organic (carbon containing) entity. For e.g. In plants, a fraction of tritium enters as $\ce{HTO}$ and incorporate into organic compounds to form OBT (organically bound tritium). Subsequently, metabolic reactions result in the incorporation of OBT in complex molecules such as polysaccharides, proteins, lipids and nucleic acids.
